# Ingresar a una USB con subprocess

Tags: python, cmd

Estoy intentando ingresar a una **USB** desde **Python** utilizando el modulo **subprocess**, ¿Como es eso de ingresar? Lo que se hace en la **CMD** para navegar hasta una **USB** conectada, algo así:

```
C:\Users\Yo> I:
I:\>
```

Donde "I" es una unidad **USB** conectada, al ingresar dicha nomenclatura seguido de dos puntos se ingresa a la unidad desde la **CMD** y ya ciertos comandos iran entorno a la unidad. He intentado lo siguiente con **subprocess**, he añadido un archivo a la unidad **USB** e intentado eliminarlo:

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['I:'], shell = True)
subprocess.run(['del archivo.txt'], shell = True)
```

La consola de Sublime Text me arroja lo siguiente: ***""del archivo.txt"" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.***

Tambien intenté algo con **os.system**

```
import os

os.system("I:")
os.system("del archivo.txt")
```

La consola me dice: ***No se pudo encontrar C:\Users\Yo\Desktop\test\archivo.txt***

Es decir, no me está ejecutando el primer comando pero el segundo sí, porque está buscando eliminar **archivo.txt** en la carpeta donde está alojado el script python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada vez que llamas a `subprocess.run` (con `shell=True`) o a `os.system` lanzas un nuevo subproceso con una nueva instancia de la terminal. Es decir, **ambos comandos  se ejecutan, pero lo hacen en terminales diferentes**.

Lo más simple es que encadenes ambos comandos:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('I: && del archivo.txt', shell=True)
```

Cuando lances el subproceso a través de la terminal (`shell=True`) no uses una lista, pasa el comando como una cadena idéntica a cómo la usarías en la propia terminal. Ten en cuenta que en este caso, subprocess lo único que hace es ejecutar la shell en un nuevo proceso y le pasa el comando sin más a la misma, la cual se encarga de ejecutarlo.

Comment: Clara, precisa y corta tu respuesta, resuelto el problema, gracias @FJSevilla